# Which tutorails can help in understanding hardware interaction with C

Tags: c, data-structures, programming-languages

I want to learn hardcore c programming used in Linux kernel but when i read those stuff everything goes on the top of my head. i am not able to understand the code and dat structures they use  with pointer to pointer function. its all very confusing with me. I have been trying for long time but i am not able to find a resource where someone has fullyy documented the harware interaction code explaining each and every line of code.

Can anyone point me in right direction how should i go

Comment: When what you call "hardcore c programming" "goes on the top of your head", then maybe you should practice patience and practice C, young padawan. When you start playing soccer, you can't start immediately in champions league.

Comment: I agree with that but there is GAP btween the books on C language which contains variables , functions etc and the code for hardware like in Kernel. There is no comparison at all . i finished many books on kernel understanding topics but i was not able to understand one page of code what they are doing. Just full text of code with no explanation. if you can give me some internet article on that i will be very happy

Comment: Have you tried looking at "Lions commentary on Unix" or Tanenbaums "Design and implementation". Both attempt to break down the source code to operating systems and explaining as you read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems: understanding some quite sophisticated language constructs: pointers to function pointers I would guess are probably only a small part, I'll bet there are some much  gnarlier things going on when you have multiple threads of control. Then there is the problem domain to which these techniques are being applied - really low level stuff interacting with hardware.

You are probably being unrealistic in expecting to learn these two things at the same time. To take an analogy, imagine asking for something to explain Shakespear's plays (say Merchant of Venice) line by line, to someone who neither speaks English, not understands the concepts of lending money or of a legal system.

My recommendation: Study C coding in detail until you understand in general how to use function pointers, and more important *why* you use them, how to write multi-threaded  code, why you need concepts such a mutices and sempahores. Then also read about the general principles of low level programming, for example [Deitel & Deitel](http://www.deitel.com/Books/OperatingSystems/OperatingSystems3e/tabid/1711/Default.aspx) covers a lot of material about OS development.

Answer (score 0):

I learned a lot about writing modules by reading this book (it's free): http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

It is a very understandable introduction to kernel development.

You might also want to have a look at this old paper:
http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/cacm.html

It explains very concisely the concepts in Unix and may help you to keep things simple.